# Why is my cross_val_score always different even when I have set my random state beforehand?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, random-seed, scoring

I am quite new to machine learning and I have recently ran into an issue I'm not sure about. When I run the code (as shown) in Jupyter Notebook it gives me a different score each time and I am not sure why?

I thought by setting the random_state or seed for the KFold that it would give me the same score each time for my `cross_val_score`?

```py
results = []
names = []

seed=12

for name, model in models:
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train.ravel(), cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = '{}:  score: {:.2f},  std_dev:{:.2f}'.format(name, 
    cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()) 
    print(msg)
```

Some example outputs:

```
LR:  score: -24.69,  std_dev: 19.74  
LASSO:  score: -29.82,  std_dev: 20.94  
EN:  score: -28.59,  std_dev: 19.79  
KNN:  score: -38.66,  std_dev: 28.77  
CART:  score: -16.42,  std_dev: 15.39  
SVR:  score: -60.53,  std_dev: 44.24
```

For the second run with the same code (same seed also):

```
LR:  score: -24.69,  std_dev: 19.74  
LASSO:  score: -29.82,  std_dev: 20.94  
EN:  score: -28.59,  std_dev: 19.79  
KNN:  score: -38.66,  std_dev: 28.77  
CART:  score: -18.65,  std_dev: 17.91  
SVR:  score: -60.53,  std_dev: 44.24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, random_state=seed)`, I think you need to add `shuffle = True`, if not, `shuffle = False` by default and `random_state` has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

In `sklearn`, [decision trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) and [random forests](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) also depend on randomness, and you will consequently need to set the random states for those estimators to ensure reproducibility.

Note that the scores for the other models are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that now.